# Azure Status RSS feed

Tags: azure, service, rss, status

Can anyone retrieve useful information from any of the Azure status page RSS feeds?

While there are RSS icons all over the http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status site, not a single one of them displays an RSS feed that ever contains any data.

Is there some documentation or blog somewhere that would explain how to leverage the RSS feed of this page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> While there are RSS icons all over the
>   http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status site, not a single one of them
>   displays an RSS feed that ever contains any data.

You only see data coming in RSS feed when there's an issue. For example, right now there's an issue with Cloud Services and I see the following:

[image]

If the services are healthy, you don't see anything in the RSS feed.